# How To Get Vaue From Nuxt Auth In A Store From Backend

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, store, auth0

I am following this https://github.com/nuxt/example-auth0 tutorial to add auth0 in my app. That works fine with this.$auth.user. But I want to get User details from database. I am using graphql hasura apollo to run queries. **where I have to update this value in Nuxt app either in store/index.js file or somewhere else
For example with this $store.state.user.name working with auth0 but i want to get $store.state.user.first_name(that is from database)**